# Merge big Azure blobs to one local file using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using python 3.6 with python SDKs for Azure blob version 1.5.0 and would like to merge multiple Azure blobs into single local file.
I managed to do that but when I try to append a blob which exceeds the machine memory the operation fails.
What is the best way to write the blob content into a file by chunks?
This is my code which does not work for blobs that are bigger than the machine memory

```
blob_files_names = blob_service.list_blob_names(container_name=blob_container_name, prefix=prefix)
with open(trg_path, 'wb') as file:
    for blob_file_name in blob_files_names:
        blob = blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(container_name=blob_container_name, blob_name=blob_file_name)
        file.write(blob.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to do it by using the function [`get_blob_to_path`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.get_blob_to_path) with append open mode.
It works because this function write each blob content to the end of the file by chunks of size  [`MAX_CHUNK_GET_SIZE`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.file.fileservice.html#azure.storage.file.fileservice.FileService.MAX_CHUNK_GET_SIZE)

```
blob_files_names = blob_service.list_blob_names(container_name=blob_container_name, prefix=prefix)
for blob_file_name in blob_files_names:
    blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name=blob_container_name, blob_name=blob_file_name,
                                  file_path=trg_path, max_connections=1, open_mode='ab')
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it sounds like there are some large blobs which size exceed the memory size of your local machine, because the function `get_blob_to_bytes` you used will temporarily read blob content to memory for writing later.

So please use the other function [`get_blob_to_stream`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.get_blob_to_stream) instead of `get_blob_to_bytes`.

Here is my sample code, my virtual environment is based on Python 3.7 with Azure Storage SDK via `pip install azure-storage-blob==1.5.0`.

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'

blob_service = BaseBlobService(account_name, account_key)

blob_container_name = '<your container name>'
prefix = '<your blob prefix>'
blob_files_names = blob_service.list_blob_names(container_name=blob_container_name, prefix=prefix)

# from io import BytesIO
from io import FileIO

trg_path = '<your target file path>'
# with open(trg_path, 'wb') as file:
with FileIO(trg_path, 'wb') as file:
    for blob_file_name in blob_files_names:
        #blob = blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(container_name=blob_container_name, blob_name=blob_file_name)
        print(blob_file_name)
        # stream = BytesIO()
        blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name=blob_container_name, blob_name=blob_file_name, stream=file)
        # file.write(stream.getbuffer())
```

<s>Note: the [`getbuffer()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getbuffer) of the `stream` of `BytesIO` above will not create a copy of the values in the BytesIO buffer and will hence not consume large amounts of memory.</s>

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried it and it doesn't work. The whole blob content is written to the memory before writing to the disk. I probably need to write it by chunks.